# get the host name from url

Tags: php, url, get, host

This is the function that get the hostname from the URL:

```
<?php

function get_domain($url)
{
  $pieces = parse_url($url);
  $domain = isset($pieces['host']) ? $pieces['host'] : '';
  if (preg_match('/(?P<domain>[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]{1,63}\.[a-z\.]{2,6})$/i', $domain, $regs)) {
    return $regs['domain'];
  }
  return false;
}

print get_domain("http://fileflyer.com"); 

?>
```

**I want to insert this function in my file here:**

```
<?php
function connect($host,$username,$database,$password){
 $to_connect = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password) or die ("UNFinded ".$username. " DB !");
 $db = mysql_select_db($database, $to_connect) or die (mysql_error());
 return $db;
}
connect("localhost","idevice2_ariel","idevice2_ariel","ariel123456");


if (!isset($_POST['submit_form'])) {
    echo '<form name="search_form1" id="form" method="POST" action="search.php">
<input type="text" style="width: 300px; display: block; margin: 0 auto; height: 36px; text-align: center; font-size: 16px;" name="search_name" placeholder="חפש סרט או סדרה.." />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit_form" />
</form>';
} else {
       $search_name = $_POST['search_name'];
       $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE (`moviename` like '%".$search_name."%')");
       $count = mysql_num_rows($query);
       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
       $fname = $row['moviename'];
       $lname = $row['links'];
       **print '<a href="'.**$row['links']**.'">'.$row['moviename'].'</a><br />';
```

I want this get the host name from the

```
$row['links']


}
}
mysql_close($to_connect);
?>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
a {

}
</style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: 1) Put it at the top of the file 2) Done

Comment: I suggest using [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php) for PHP database access as mysql_* will be depreciated as of php 5.5

Comment: And stop using `mysql` function, and give `PDO` or `MySQLi` a try

Comment: i am Beginner, somebody can help my with that? (and make the changes in the line i need?) please and very thanks you for your answers!

Comment: As a code-review type note, the `return false;` as a fallback in your `get_domain` function is probably a bad choice - unless you remember to check for it every time, it is equivalent to returning an empty string, which is probably not very useful. A better option would be to return `$url` immediately if `$pieces['host']` is empty, and return `$pieces['host']` if the regular expression doesn't match.

Answer (score 1):

Why you just don´t copy your `get_domain()` function into the other file, just after the connect function ? That should work!

Comment: i need to put that in this line :
 print '<a href="'.**$row['links']**.'">'.$row['moviename'].'</a><br />';

Comment: Try this: print '<a href="' . get_domain("http://fileflyer.com")  .**$row['links']**.'">'.$row['moviename'].'</a><br />';

Comment: arielcr :( no dude it dont work :(

i dont want "fileflyer.com" i trying to insert the link from data base. he is $row['links'] .

Answer (score 0):

A function you have written can be used anywhere within the same file it is declared, it doesn't have to be immediately afterwards - indeed that's part of the point of it being a function in the first place! So add your function definition to the top of the file next to the definition of `function connect( ... )`, and then in your HTML, you can just use it:

```
echo '<a href="'.get_domain($row['links']).'">'.$row['moviename'].'</a><br />';
```

(Note that I've used `echo` rather than `print` - they do the same thing, but `echo` is the more commonly used name in PHP.)

As your program grows, you will probably want to put your function definitions into a file and reuse them in multiple pages, and even group them into categories, and so on. This is what [`include` and `require`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) (and their variants `include_once` and `require_once`) are for.

**Edit**: Since your function returns part of the domain (I'm not clear what your function does that `parse_url` doesn't already, but never mind), this will result in links like `<a href="exmple.com">...</a>` which would link to a page called `example.com` *on your site*. You may actually want to make this into an "absolute" URL by prefixing with `'http://'`, e.g.

```
echo '<a href="http://'.get_domain($row['links']).'">'.$row['moviename'].'</a><br />';
```

Even if you do have a page like that on your site, you probably want to make the URL relative to the root of your domain, not in the current directory, in which case you would need a leading `'/'`:

```
echo '<a href="/'.get_domain($row['links']).'">'.$row['moviename'].'</a><br />';
```

Comment: i want to print both the $row['links'].
and the
.$row['moviename']
and add to them the get_domain($row['links'] 

please help me to do that!

Comment: What is your problem? You can print as many things as you want.